# updating n number of records mysql database

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-5.7, limits

I want to update n number of records in table using a query like below, but it will return an error since in mysql, it is not allowed to use value after the limit key

```
update producedItem pi 
inner join productionOrderLine pol on pol.id = pi.productionOrderLineId
set pi.isReserved = 1
limit floor(pol.quantity - pol.availableQuantity);
```

what would be the better alternative?

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example what you are trying to achieve, you have to rewrite teh query so that you get a WHERE withouot using the LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

Write a Stored Procedure that 'constructs' the query, specifically by putting a computed value after `LIMIT`.